# Parametrize portlets and access these params from vm-side

Tags: liferay, portlet

I have portlets, and I want to separate them on two groups by some static property. By static I mean this property is the same for all instances (so, it is not the same like portlet configuration as far as I understand it - quite possible, I'm wrong).

So, what is the best way to differ this portlets in liferay vm-based theme?
Off the top of my head, I can imagine that I'm putting a properties file which I can access from servlet context. This solution is terrifying me (reading file on each request?!!), besides, I don't know how I exactly can access servlet context from velocity template.

I would appreciate any help with humility.

Comment: What will you do differently between the two groups? I mean, what is the purpose of separating these portlets in two groups? What are you trying to do in the high level?

Comment: @brandizzi One these groups is for extjs-based UIs. Thus, I want to provide even portlet title rendering via extjs. Nevertheless, there a "simple" portlets. I need to know in my layout which type of port let I am currently rendering.

Comment: @shabunc won't the `portletId` help in knowing which portlet you are deploying?